# Nudge vector X towards/away vector A

Tags: python, vector, formula, similarity, dot-product

I have :

```
d1 = np.dot(a,x)
```

the question is what formula I can use to modify X, so that :

```
d2 = d1 + delta
```

where "delta" is a parameter/number, specified by me.

In addition as a second case "delta" could be (d1*percent)

---

I'm looking for 'F' :

```
x1 = x * F
```

so that :

```
d2 = np.dot(a,x1)
```

said otherwise :

```
d1 + delta = np.dot(a, x * F)
```

what is 'F' ?

---

kewl ;)

```
@staticmethod
def nudge(a,b,delta):
    d = hrr.dot(a, b)
    return b * ((d+delta)/d)


In [144]: hrr.dot(a,b)                                                                                                                                                       
Out[144]: 0.03531923115430759

In [145]: hrr.dot(a,hrr.nudge(a,b,0.1))                                                                                                                                      
Out[145]: 0.13531923115430755

In [146]: hrr.dot(a,hrr.nudge(a,b,0.2))                                                                                                                                      
Out[146]: 0.2353192311543074
```

Comment: First you should tag the language usef

Comment: second you could just do `np.dot(a, x + delta/(x.size() * a))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `np.dot(a,x)` is the dot product of **a** and **x**

```
F = (d1 + delta)/d1
```

Comment: shouldn't there be 'a', somewhere ?

Comment: @sten: No, it's correct. But if you don't want it in terms of `delta` and `d1`, I can rewrite it in terms of `delta`, `a` and `x`.

Comment: how did u get it ...

Comment: @sten: The dot product of two vectors is proportional to each of the magnitudes. And |k **v** | = k| **v** |. So the factor by which you scale one vector is the same as the factor by which you scale the dot product.